# Conditional Css for text length

Tags: css

I have a div with certain text contained inside it. When the Text is of a certain length (Say 15 characters or more), the width of the div should change. Is there any way to achieve this purely via CSS?

Comment: `should change` according what?? to be as size the text inside

Comment: show your code please

Comment: No. This is not possible.

Comment: share your code

Comment: NO.. CSS can't **detect** anything. You need Javascript.

Comment: @Paulie_D Given the existence of media queries, relative units like `vw`, `vh`, `%`, and `em` (which all arguably *detect* the context of and within a given element), pseudoclass selectors (which detect context and user interaction), and functions (which could be specified for anything), I think it's patently false to simply assert that `CSS` can't detect anything. With a single new function or pseudo-class, it *would* be possible to change CSS behaviour based on text length.

Comment: Nope. Browsers detect things and apply the appropriate CSS, not the other way around.

Comment: @Paulie_D but in CSS you can work with the values the browsers dynamically detect, so this is nothing more than useless word lawyering

Answer (score 0):

with pure css, you can only fit `content` with `div`:

```
div { display:inline-block;}
```

else if you want more complicated conditions, You can't do it with pure css.you must help of javascript like this:

```
var con = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
if((con[0].innerHTML).length >= 15) { con[0].style.width = '300px'; }
```

```js
var con = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
if((con[0].innerHTML).length >= 15)
  con[0].style.width = '300px';
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>This is more 15 characters</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS for it...
if `textContent.length > 15` the add class to label and style in css(`width` and ect)

```js
var lbl=document.querySelector(".lbl");
if(lbl.textContent.length > 15){
   lbl.classList.add('bigger');
}
```

```css
.bigger{
color:red
}
```

```html
<label class="lbl">avvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvb<label>
```